# AppDatabase instantiation always null even after initialization

Tags: java, android-room

I am implementing an android app which retrieves my device location and store it in a table . I first instantiate AppDataBase Class and then initialize it in the onCreate() method . But when it comes to call a Dao method , i always get the error :
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.locator.Interfaces.LocationDao com.example.locator.AppDatabase.locationDao()' on a null object reference

Here is the code i've implemented :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
        AppDatabase appDatabase;
        private Handler handler;
        List<String> newPermissions;
    
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
            appDatabase=AppDatabase.getDbIntance(this);
            newPermissions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA));
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) newPermissions.add(Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
    
            if(!checkPermission(this, newPermissions)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, newPermissions.toArray(new String[]{}), 200);
            }
    
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Request location updates
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new MainActivity());
    
            handler = new Handler();
    
            // Define the code block to be executed
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Insert custom code here
    
                    Log.d("TAG", "run: " + "run every 30s");
    
                    if(appDatabase!=null){
                        if(appDatabase.locationDao().getAll()!=null){
                            //  List<GpsLocation> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> appDatabase.locationDao().getAll().observe(MainActivity.this, locations -> {
    
                                Collections.reverse(locations);
                                if(locations.size()>0){
                                    binding.Longitude.setText("Longitude : "+locations.get(0).getLongitude());
                                    binding.Latitude.setText("Latitude : "+locations.get(0).getLatitude());
                                    binding.Altitude.setText("Altitude : "+locations.get(0).getAltitude());
                                    binding.Accuracy.setText("Accuracy : "+locations.get(0).getAccuracy());
                                    binding.send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
    
    
                            }));
                            binding.send.setOnClickListener(v->{
    
                            });
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    // Repeat every 30 seconds
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 30000L);
                }
            };
            handler.post(runnable);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: checking .... ");
            if(location.getAccuracy()<=5f){
                GpsLocation position=new GpsLocation();
                if(position!=null){
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: accuracy <=5");
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    position.setLatitude(latitude);
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    position.setLongitude(longitude);
                    double altitude=location.getAltitude();
                    position.setAltitude(altitude);
                    float accuracy=location.getAccuracy();
                    position.setAccuracy(accuracy);
                    //TODO: send message with positions
                }else{
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: position is null");
                }
    
            }else{
                GpsLocation position=new GpsLocation();
                if(position!=null){
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: accuracy >=5");
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    position.setLatitude(latitude);
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    position.setLongitude(longitude);
                    double altitude=location.getAltitude();
                    position.setAltitude(altitude);
                    float accuracy=location.getAccuracy();
                    position.setAccuracy(accuracy);
                    appDatabase.locationDao().insert(position);//Here is the part highlighted when    i get the error
                }else{
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: position is null");
    
                }
    
    
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {
            LocationListener.super.onProviderEnabled(provider);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
            LocationListener.super.onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    
            if(requestCode == 200){
                for(int g : grantResults){
                    if(g != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission non accorde", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        private boolean checkPermission(Context context, List<String> permissions){
            for(String p : permissions){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, p) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

//Here is my AppDataBase class : 

@Database(entities = {GpsLocation.class} , version =2)

public abstract  class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract LocationDao locationDao();
    public static AppDatabase instance;

    public static AppDatabase  getDbIntance(Context c){
        if (instance ==null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(c.getApplicationContext() , AppDatabase.class , "LocationDb" )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's `AppDatabase.getDbIntance(this)`?

Comment: this is how i instantiate my appDataBase variable

Comment: Post that class as well, specifically that method.